# Passing multiple variables into WHERE condition in PL/SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql

There is a problem executing this block of code while passing the parameter. Parameter *rf* is a list of variables to be input into the WHERE clause. The number of variables to be input is not static.

```
create or replace
procedure test_pl(rf in varchar2)
IS 
counter number;

BEGIN
  select count(*) into counter from test_pl_imp where column_name in (rf);
  dbms_output.put_line(counter);
END;
```

The execution code is as follows:

```
declare 
inparam varchar2(20) := 'xyz,ran,dom';
begin
goku.test_pl(inparam);
end;
/
```

I want the WHERE condition to be executed like :

```
where column_name in ('xyz','ran','dom');
```

But it gets executed considering `xyz,ran,dom` as a string itself.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either explode the string out or the simplest way would be to use INSTR.

```
rf := ',' || rf || ',';

SELECT
    COUNT(*)
INTO
    counter
FROM
    test_pl_imp
WHERE
    INSTR(rf, ',' || column_name || ',') > 0;
```

If you have the option to redesign this slightly, I think it would be a cleaner design to take an array of strings and you casting it to a TABLE so that you can join to test_pl_imp.

This could be done as follows:

```
DECLARE
    l_array   goku.t_type := goku.t_type();
BEGIN
    l_array.extend(3);
    l_array(1) := 'xzy';
    l_array(2) := 'abc';
    l_array(2) := '123';

    goku.test_pl(l_array);
END;
```

And then your package spec would including the following since you want the types and procedures public for the above call:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE goku
    TYPE r_type IS RECORD (
        search_term    VARCHAR2 (30)
    );

    TYPE t_type IS TABLE OF r_type;

    PROCEDURE test_pl(l_array IN t_type);
END goku;
```

And your package body would be something like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY goku
    PROCEDURE test_pl(l_array IN t_type) IS
        v_counter NUMBER;
    BEGIN

        SELECT
            COUNT(tpi.*)
        INTO
            v_counter
        FROM
            test_pl_imp tpi
            , TABLE( CAST(l_array as r_type)) la
        WHERE
            tpi.column_name = la.search_term;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Count :' || v_counter);
    END;
END goku;
```

Comment: INSTR may have issues with things like "MyString" and "MyStringTest" when provided ONLY "MyString" as the variable.  But to get around it, you could pad the original value with a special character and the variable so it would look for ";MyString;" instead.  I've done this trick before as well.

Comment: Close... You need to pad the beginning as well for the first value in the list.  +1 anyway.  Good job!

Comment: Ah again you are correct - I forgot what would happen if you searched just for yz.

Comment: @Chris .. thanks a lot for your help! very nice 'tricks' to remember. worked like a miracle!!

Comment: Just a doubt: can you tell me how to use an `array` of variable length in WHERE clause pl/sql?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

1. convert your stored proc query to a dynamic query and pass the value as '''abc'',''etc'''
2. implement a split function to split the string into a temp table and join/query against it.
3. You can use INSTR, but there's a trick to it.

I've written a split function where I work and it works out great for stuff like this.

---

INSTR trick:  You're currently passing comma as your separator, so that's what I used in the 'trick', but you could also use a semi-colon.  Basically, let's say you want to find everything in 'abc,def'.  You pad your string to make it look like ',abc,def,' then pad the value being searched so it looks like ',abc,'.  This way, 'abctest' and 'testabc' are not found, while 'abc' is found.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
INTO 
    counter 
FROM 
    test_pl_imp 
WHERE 
    INSTR(',' + rf + ',', ',' + column_name + ',') > 0;
```

Sorry if I don't know PL/SQL well enough... the + signs I think need to be ||, but I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a paramater as a single string(varchar), it will be treated as a unique string then.
You can try splitting the parameter : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str

Answer (score 1):

You could split your input string and either use a temporary table or a table object. This will allow the optimizer to use an index on your column. Don't use dynamic SQL without binds (for security and performance reasons).

Here's an example with a table object. Setup (10g since it uses [REGEXP_SUBSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions150.htm#SQLRF06303)):

```
CREATE TYPE tab_varchar2 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);-- longest string
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_pl(rf IN VARCHAR2) IS
   lt tab_varchar2;
   counter NUMBER;
BEGIN
   -- split parameter
   SELECT rtrim(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]*,', 1, level), ',')
     BULK COLLECT INTO lt
     FROM (SELECT rf || ',' str FROM dual)
  CONNECT BY level <= length(str) - length(replace(str, ',', ''));
   -- your query
   SELECT count(*)
     INTO counter
     FROM test_pl_imp
    WHERE column_name IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(lt));
   dbms_output.put_line(counter);
END;
/
```